# Why would there be inconsistency when saving NSManagedObjectContext after adding NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

I have an app that uses Core Data to persist a store of **Events**.

An **Event** has an optional `location` (stored as a `CLLocation`) as one of its attributes. In my model, this `location` attribute has the type Transformable:

[image: location attribute of Transformable type]

My app has been in production for several years and everything's been working reliably, but some time in the past year I started getting an error in the Xcode console telling me I should *switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead*.

After doing some research (I'd consider myself a novice at Core Data) I determined I should write a `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` subclass and put the name of that class in the **Transformer** field for the `location` attribute, which was blank, with the *Value Transformer Name* placeholder text:

[image: blank Transformer field]

From what I found online, the subclass could be pretty straightforward for a Transformable attribute that contains a `CLLocation`:

```
@objc(CLLocationValueTransformer)
final class CLLocationValueTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
    
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: CLLocationValueTransformer.self))
    
    override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [CLLocation.self]
    }
    
    public static func register() {
        let transformer = CLLocationValueTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

So, I made this subclass in my project and put the class name in the **Transformer** field for the `location` attribute:

[image: filled-in Transformer field]

---

But now, here's the problem:
**Once I started using my app after implementing the Transformer, I started getting unpredictable results.**

Sometimes, when I created a new `Event`, it disappeared at the next app launch. It was not persisted by Core Data across app launches, like it was before the change.

Sometimes `Event`s were saved, but sometimes they were not.

I couldn't figure out a clear pattern. They were not always saved if the  `location` was included when it was first created, but sometimes they were. It seemed like other times the original `Event` was saved, but without `location` if the `location` was added later.

I've left out the boilerplate Core Data code, but basically I have `baseManagedObjectContext`, which is the layer that's connected to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to save data to disk.

`baseManagedObjectContext` is a parent to `mainObjectContext`, which is used by most of my UI. Then I create private contexts to write changes to first before saving them.

Here is example code to create a new `Event` with a possible `location` and save it, which was working consistently for years before adding the `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` subclass as the **Transformer** on `location`. I added `fatalError` for debugging, but it was never called, even when my data didn't fully save to disk:

```
private func addEvent(location: CLLocation?) {
    
    let privateLocalContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateLocalContext.parent = coreDataStack.mainObjectContext
    privateLocalContext.undoManager = nil
    
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event",
                                            in: privateLocalContext)
    
    let newEvent = Event(entity: entity!,
                         insertInto: privateLocalContext)
    
    if let location = location {
        newEvent.location = location
    }
    
    privateLocalContext.performAndWait {
        do {
            try privateLocalContext.save()
        }
        catch { fatalError("error saving privateLocalContext") }
    }
    
    coreDataStack.mainObjectContext.performAndWait {
        do {
            try coreDataStack.mainObjectContext.save()
        }
        catch { fatalError("error saving mainObjectContext") }
    }
    
    coreDataStack.baseManagedObjectContext.perform {
        do {
            try coreDataStack.baseManagedObjectContext.save()
        }
        catch { fatalError("error saving baseManagedObjectContext") }
    }
}
```

With further debugging, I found that sometimes, even if the change was making it to `mainObjectContext`, it was not making it all the way to `baseManagedObjectContext`, or to disk. I created a whole separate Core Data stack for testing to read directly from disk.

This issue with the saves not propogating (like they did before, for years) is what was causing the data to not persist across app launches, but I do not understand why this would suddenly start happening after my addition of the **Transformer** on `location`.

**What am I missing here with how Core Data works?**

I did not think I was fundamentally changing anything when I switched from a blank **Transformer** field to a subclass of `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`, but clearly something is going on that I don't understand.

I'd like to adopt `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`, since Apple is recommending it. How can I change what I'm doing to be able to adopt it and have data save consistently?

For now, I've switched back to the blank **Transformer** field to keep things working like they did before.

Comment: What you describe *sounds like* a concurrency issue (and I can see that your code to create a new Event object and insert it into the private context is not in the performAndWait block).  I would start by enabling CoreData concurrency debugging and see if that gives a clue.

Comment: I actually tried the new Event code inside the block with the same outcome. But ohhhh my... do I ever have some concurrency issues. Thank you so much. I did not know about the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` argument before looking into your comment. I just launched my app with it and it's looking like the issues run deep. Here I thought I was handling concurrency correctly and it must have been blind luck that this app was working reliabliy for people for years without many issues. But my work is cut out for me now! Thanks again!

Comment: Just to be candid, you'll find some Q&A here suggesting that the concurrency debug option gives false alerts.  But worth investigating anyway.  And it might yet be a separate problem from your ValueTransformer issue.